# Which currently active chess player tends to play complicated positions?

Tags: famous-players

In earlier years, Michail Tal would be a candidate for this topic.

Which player could be a candidate today for regularly playing complicated positions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander Morozevich probably obtains the most consistently complicated positions of any >2700 player, although he has fallen off some since the mid-2000s.

Baadur Jobava is probably his rightful successor, but a recent string of horrible tournaments pushed him under 2700 and he is now sitting at 2699.

Answer (score 1):

Richard Rapport plays a lot of novelties in the opening. You can search for it. The positions are not necessarily tactically complicated, but the novelties are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Nakamura, Mamedyarov, Topalov, Svidler, Shirov, Jobava